# Is upsert thread safe in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table `t in a server(port 5001).

```
t:([] sym:`GOOG`AMZN; px:100 2000)
```

We have two clients which upserts simultaneously data to the table t.

```
Client 1:
h:hopen 5001
do[10; h"`t upsert ({x}rand `GOOG`AMZN;{x}rand 10)"]

Client 2:
h:hopen 5001
do[10; h"`t upsert ({x}rand `GOOG`AMZN;{x}100+rand 10)"]
```

I have two questions based on above scenario:
1. Is the upsert thread safe when mutiple threads/processes are updating the table simultaneously?
2. Will the thread behaviour be same in case table t is keyed on column sym?

Comment: I would be wary of upserting into a keyed tables by two or more clients. If they both update GOOG for example, whichever clients query was processed last will be the value shown in t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t generally have to worry about thread safety when working with kdb (unless you do some intricate things with your own C code which spawns it’s own threads or something). The reason is there’s only one thread responsible for processing user queries and queries from Client1 and Client 2 will be processed one at a time.

There’s a so called multithreaded input query input mode (https://code.kx.com/q/kb/multithreaded-input/) but it has it’s own restrictions which means you will never experience inconsistent reads.

Answer (score 1):

Thread safety can be assumed, if an action isn't thread-safe kdb will throw a `noupdate` error. In your case, kdb handles the IPC calls one by one, so there is definitely thread-safety, the upsert is not being performed in a multithreaded fashion.

Multiple processes upserting to the same table concurrently would be a concern however, do not attempt this.